# Sagging flat-bread after proofing

Tags: bread, sourdough

I have been making sourdough bread for quite a long time (almost a year) and am starting to up the hydration percentage from 60-65% to like 70-75%.
When I do this, I am fine with activating the gluten and I get a dough that will spring back perfectly into a ball if you try to stretch it. But when I do the bulk rise and the final proofing at the start, I have a dough that will comfortably hold its weight on the bench in a ball without deforming but when it has finished proofing the top will be completely flat and the dough doesn't get that nice round top once it has baked. what can I do to stop the dough going flat and sagging?

Answer (score 3):

It appears likely that you are over-proofing your dough, now.

If you are strictly following the same exact procedure, but you've changed one variable in hydration percentage, and you observe that the loaf behaves differently, you then need to look for other variables that may need to be changed to get the result you want, rather than the result you are now getting.

In the described loaf, the flat result after proofing suggests that it's over-proofed, that is, proofed for too long. Try less time, or less size (depending on the method you use to determine the endpoint that it's proofed.) Leave some life in the dough for oven spring.